# Get methods covered by a unit test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, visual-studio-addins

Is is possible to do the following from a Visual Studio 2010 plugin? If yes, how?

1. Run all unittests in solution (with code coverage enabled)
2. Wait for all tests to complete
3. For successfully completed tests: Determine which methods were called during each test (directly by the test or indirectly by the tested methods). And store their names in a variable in the plugin.

What I actually don't know is how to interact with the testing framework from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff420671.aspx